# Determine parent, children from pairwise data

Tags: algorithm

I need to determine parent/child relationships from some unusual data.

Flight numbers are marketing creations and they are odd.  Flight # 22 by Airline X may refer to a singular trip between X and Y.   Flight # 44 from the same airline may actually refer to multiple flights between city pairs.  Example:

```
Flight 44:  Dallas - Paris
Flight 44:  Dallas - Chicago
Flight 44:  Chicago - New York
Flight 44:  New York - Paris
Flight 44:  Chicago - Paris
Flight 44:  Dallas - New York
```

Reality -- this is the way they work.  When I pull the data from the "big list of flight numbers and city pairs"  I get those 6 combinations for flight 44.  I have passenger counts for each, so if there are 10 people flying Dallas - Paris, I need to take those 10 passengers and add them to the DAL - CHI, CHI - NY, and NY - PAR segments.

From a list of all the segments, I need to figure out  "ahhh, this is a flight that goes from Dallas to Paris" --then when I see passenger loads I can increment the city-to-city actual loads accordingly like so:

```
- Value associated with AD -- > increment segments AB, BC, CD
- value associated with AC -->  increment only segments AB, BC
- value associated with AB --> increment only segment AB
etc.
```

Assume I get a list of values in no order for flight 44 like this: (DAL-CHI, CHI-NYC, NYC-PAR, DAL-NYC, DAL-PAR, CHI-PAR).  How do I figure out the parent child structure comparing these 4 values in these 6 combinations?

Comment: I do not understand what are "aggregations", and therefore I do not see why `- Value associated with AD -- > increment segments AB, BC, CD` etc. Is that because there is a path from A to D composed of these segments? Is it guaranteed that it is the only path? Also, what is a child and what is a parent.

Comment: Fair enough, ondav -- more to be added above with thanks.

Comment: @ToddCurry Make sure to take a looksee at my answer - this is a common problem with an existing algorithm ready for you to use. You don't need to invent anything new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, take two: here's a function that will take a string such as the one you provided and topologically sort it as per that wikipedia article.

```
import re
import itertools

def create_nodes(segments):
    remaining_segments = re.findall(r'(\w*?)-(\w*?)[,)]', segments)
    nodes = []
    while len(remaining_segments) > 1:
        outgoing, incoming = zip(*remaining_segments)
        point = next(node for node in outgoing if node not in incoming)
        nodes.append(point)
        remaining_segments = [segment for segment in remaining_segments if segment[0] != point]
    last_segment = remaining_segments.pop()
    nodes.extend(last_segment)
    return nodes
```

Test:

```
>>> foo = '(DAL-CHI, CHI-NYC, NYC-PAR, DAL-NYC, DAL-PAR, CHI-PAR)'
>>> scratch.create_nodes(foo)
['DAL', 'CHI', 'NYC', 'PAR']
```

Note that this is not a perfect topological sort function for every use; however, for your specific use case of multiple-stop one-way journeys it should be effective.

Comment: llb, my thanks for your submission and my apologies but the exact order A, B, C, D is not known a priori.   From a list of letter combinations, I'd like to figure out the actual A, B, C, D order.  Please take a look at my edits above and perhaps you will see a solution that I regret I cannot.  Best, TC

Answer (score 4):

## Formulation

Let `a_i -> b_i` be the `i`th entry in your list of pairs for flight 44, `i = 1..M`.

Let `V` be the set of all unique `a_i` and `b_i` values:

```
V = {a_i | i = 1..M} U {b_i | i = 1..M}
```

Let `E` be the set of all pairs `(a_i, b_i)`:

```
E = {(a_i, b_i) | i = 1..M}
```

Then `G = (V, E)` is a [**directed acyclic graph**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) where vertices `V` are cities and directed edges `E` correspond to entries `a_i -> b_i` in your list.

## Algorithm

What you are looking for is a [**topological sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the graph `G`. The linked Wikipedia page has pseudocode for this algorithm.

This will give you a linear ordering of the cities (in your example: `[Dallas, Chicago, New York, Paris]`) that is consistent with all of the ordering constraints present in your initial list. If your initial list contains fewer than `|V| choose 2` pairs (meaning there is not a full set of constraints) then there will potentially be multiple consistent topological orderings of the cities in your set `V`.

Comment: For practical purposes, I accepted ondav's answer, Timothy, but I wish I could accept both as your answer is clearly one that will help many others tackle this class of problem.  I have up voted it with my thanks.  TC

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is a common-sense analysis, but see Timothy Shields solution where he identified the problem as Topological Sorting problem, thus having known computation complexity & known conditions on uniqueness.

I will try to extract the core of the problem from your answer in order to describe it formally.

In the above example, you actually have four nodes (cities), for brevity denoted as D, P, C, and NY. You have a set of ordered pairs (x, y), which are interpreted as "on that flight, node x precedes node y". Writing this as `x<y`, we actually have the following:

(for flight 044):

```
D < P
D < C
C < NY
NY < P
C < P
D < NY
```

From these constraints, we want to find an ordered tuple `(x, y, z, w)` such that `x < y < z < w` and the above constraints hold. We know that the solution is `(x=D, y=C, z=NY, w=P)`.

Note: It might be that in your database, the first element in your set is always the "origin-destination pair" (in our case, `D<P`). But it does not change much on the analysis which follows.

How to find this ordered tuple programatically? I have relatively fair knowledge of algorithms, but am not aware of a standard method for solving this (other users may help here). I am concerned about the uniqueness of the result. It could be a good unit test of the integrity of your data that you should require that the solution for that ordered tuple is unique, otherwise you might be, subsequently, incrementing the wrong segments.

As we deal with uniqueness issue, I would suggest generating all the permutations of nodes, and displaying all the solutions which are feasible w.r.t the given constraints.

A naive implementation could look like this:

```
import itertools 

nodes = ['D', 'P', 'NY', 'C']

result = [ot
          for ot in itertools.permutations(nodes) # ot = ordered tuple
          if ot.index('D') < ot.index('P')
          if ot.index('D') < ot.index('C')
          if ot.index('C') < ot.index('NY')
          if ot.index('NY') < ot.index('P')
          if ot.index('C') < ot.index('P')
          if ot.index('D') < ot.index('NY')
          ] 

print result

# displays: [('D', 'C', 'NY', 'P')]
```

If the number of nodes is low, this type of "naive" implementation may be sufficient. If the number is higher, I would suggest to implement it in such a way that the constrains are used effectively to prune the solution space (ask me if you would need hints for this).

Comment: You can always propose an edit for the tag change (which I've just done, BTW).

Comment: @PhilipKendall Thanks, I removed the suggestion from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a list of all cities that are either departures or destinations from your flight list. This gives four
cities:

```
Dallas
Paris
Chicago
New York
```

Iterate over the flight list again and count the number of occurances of each destination city:

```
0 Dallas
3 Paris
1 Chicago
2 New York
```

Sort the list by the destination count and you have the route:

```
Dallas -> Chicago -> New York -> Paris
```

Note: If the destination counts are not contiguous starting with zero (eg. 0, 1, 2, 3...) it points to either an inconsistent or incomplete departure/destination list for that flight.

Comment: This won't work if the list supplied is: (1) Dallas->Chicago (2) Chicago->New York (3) New York->Paris -- that seems like a case that could be reasonably expected as input. See my answer for a more-stable solution.

Comment: @TimothyShields Missing links are a problem with any algorithm. Suppose the Chicago->NY link was missing. One could determine the start/end points but not the route to get there. Dallas->NY then NY->Chicago or Dallas->Chicago then Chicago->NY could both be options.

Comment: Yes, but you will always get a consistent ordering from the topological sort.  If the end goal is to list the cities related to some flight number, then a consistent ordering is the goal (even if there is more than one consistent ordering).

Comment: So, NealB, this is an approach I started trying with a little different twist.  I need some time to grok Timothy's excellent recs, that is a separate comment.   

I created 8 lists: flights starting in A, B, C, D and flights ending at A, B, C, D.  I then populate each list as I encounter each seg, regardless of order.  The final dest is always the list of flights starting that has zero items; final origin is always the list of flights ending that is null.  Therefore I have the A and D established.  I then can work in decr freq down the lists of flights starting at a point and get the sequence.

Comment: NealB, I had to accept Ondav's answer, as it is just tricked out and perfect, but your approach here saved me a ton of time on another aspect of this problem -- my sincere thanks to you!  TC

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) with a list store in it.

a dictionary is basically a hash table and you can store a key (the begging and end point ex, AD) and a value (the segments it needs to go through [AB, BC, CD])